# Unable to generate correct char array in c++

Tags: c++, string, function

```
myFunction(){
char *tempPath = getenv("LocalAppData");
    strcat(tempPath, "\\MS\\namedPipe.json");

printf(" the path is %s \n",tempPath
}

int main(){

myFunction();
myFunction();

return 0;
}
```

I don't know the second time that I call this function I am getting the path to be appended like

[image]

Comment: How sure are you that you are allowed to append data to the string returned by `getenv`? I'd look it up and confirm if I were you.

Comment: Are you asking about c or c++?

Comment: Looks like temp is the updated string the second time the function is called... how to I clear this?

Comment: getenv is the environment table making it longer by writing to it will change the string you write to and mess things up in strings further down the table - just like making it longer by writing to argv[0] would mess up argv[1]

Comment: Becuase pointer to this char array is updated(is what my guess is ).. Is there a way I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the man page for `getenv`:

> As typically implemented, getenv() returns a pointer to a string within the environment list.  The caller must take care not to modify this string, since that would change the environment of the process.

In other words, what you are currently doing is not allowed.

Instead make another buffer and concatenate in that buffer. Eg:

```cpp
char *tempPath = getenv("LocalAppData");
if (tempPath != NULL)
{    
    std::string env;
    env = tempPath;
    env += "\\MS\\namedPipe.json"
    std::cout << env;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "No such environment variable\n";
}
```